# How to change this jquery code to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been reading and studying about this library to be able to change the code of this codebox from jquery to javascript (https://codepen.io/mrWilson123/pen/OJMVwzd?editors=1010) but I got stuck in this part.

```
$(".slide-captions").html(function () {
        return (
          "<h2 class='current-title'>" +
          currentTitle +
          "</h2>" +
          "<h3 class='current-subtitle'>" +
          currentSubtitle +
          "</h3>"
        );
      });
```

I understand that it's getting the div element and putting inner html code into it so I tried this but it didn't work.

```
document.querySelector(".slide-captions").innerHTML(
          "<h2 class='current-title'>" +
            currentTitle +
            "</h2>" +
            "<h3 class='current-subtitle'>" +
            currentSubtitle +
            "</h3>");
```

What am I doing wrong if someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: `.innerHTML = "..."` (it's a property, not a function). Please always check the API docs first, especially before posting a question.

Comment: Did you look up [what `innerHTML` is and how to use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)?

Comment: Did you open up your browser's developer tools (F12) and look at the Console? If so, you would see an error message there telling you that `innerHTML` is not a function.

Comment: As I said, I studied jquery for a while to be able to make the change and I ended up getting confused, I forgot the = , what an idiotic mistake hahaha, I should delete this question hahaha, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever appending to the `DOM`, there is a *string-oriented* approach using parse-able strings of HTML and properties and methods like:

- `.innerHTML`
- `.insertAdjacentHTML()`

There is also a *construction-oriented* approach using DOM Nodes and properties and methods like:

- `.insertBefore()` / `.before()`
- `.appendChild` / `.append()`
- `.insertAdjacentElement()`
- `.classList`

Whichever approach you normally use to build DOM, it's useful to be aware of the other approach:

### String-oriented Approach

```
let slideCaptions = document.querySelector('.slide-captions');

let myHTML = '';
myHTML += '<h2 class="current-title">' + currentTitle + '</h2>';
myHTML += '<h3 class='current-subtitle'>' + currentSubtitle + '</h3>';

slideCaptions.innerHTML = myHTML;
```

### Construction-oriented Approach

```
let slideCaptions = document.querySelector('.slide-captions');

let titleElement = document.createElement('h2');
titleElement.classList.add('current-title');
titleElement.textContent = currentTitle;
slideCaptions.appendChild(titleElement);

let subtitleElement = document.createElement('h3');
subtitleElement.classList.add('current-subtitle');
subtitleElement.textContent = currentSubtitle;
slideCaptions.appendChild(subtitleElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
document.querySelector('.slide-captions').innerHTML=`
        <h2 class='current-title'>" +
        currentTitle +
        "</h2>" +
        "<h3 class='current-subtitle'>" +
        currentSubtitle +
        "</h3>`;
```

if there any error use this instead

```
document.querySelectorAll('.slide-captions')[0] // .innerHTML ....
```

Comment: Using template literals is meant to replace fumbling around with `+`  and quotes. Use either, not both.

Comment: I did what was asked but thanks anyway